# Why HTML CSS dropdown menu not aligns to the right when float:right is set?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm using following CSS to create an drop down menu at the right top side of page. But the dropdown menu's right part is not in visible area. I tried with float:right; in each CSS block, but half of the menu is still off the screen.

```
 <style>
                            .dropbtn {
                            padding: 16px;
                            border: none;
                            }

                            .dropdown {
                            position: relative;
                            display: inline-block;
                            float:right;
                            }

                            .dropdown-content {
                            display: none;
                            position: absolute;
                            background-color: #f1f1f1;
                            min-width: 160px;
                            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                            z-index: 1;
                            float:left;
                            }

                            .dropdown-content a {
                            color: black;
                            padding: 12px 16px;
                            text-decoration: none;
                            display: block;
                            float:left;
                            }

                            .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;
                                float:left;
                            }

                            .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;float:left;}

                            .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {}
                        </style>

                           <div class="dropdown">
                                <img id="imgExtSettings" class="dropbtn" style="width:60px;height:60px;cursor:pointer;padding:10px;" src="https://findicons.com/files/icons/2146/realistik_reloaded/128/gear.png"></img>
                                <div class="dropdown-content">
                                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Can anyone please find what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make change in `.dropdown-content`

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    float:left;
}
```

make ***position:relative*** so that it's space will be included in html. this will make sure that it's drop-down contents is visible.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why some part of the dropdown was hidden is because of the `position: absolute;` property. As the dropdown is on the rightmost of the screen and the width of the dropdown is `160px`, it's flowing outside of the viewport. Consider putting `right: 0` on `.dropdown-content`. In the below code, I have also removed some redundant `float: left` properties. Hope this your expected output.

```css
.dropbtn {
  border: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <img id="imgExtSettings" class="dropbtn" src="https://findicons.com/files/icons/2146/realistik_reloaded/128/gear.png" />
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```